# MYSQL numeric datatype that can handle up to 22 digits

Tags: mysql

What MySQL numeric data type can handle up to 22 digits of number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use DECIMAL(M,D) and you can specify any

> M is the maximum number of digits (the precision). It has a range of 1
>   to 65.
>
> D is the number of digits to the right of the decimal point (the
>   scale). It has a range of 0 to 30 and must be no larger than M.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/precision-math-decimal-characteristics.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `NUMERIC(22,0)`